# UIView animation not working on text begin editing in iphone app

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uitextfield

I am making the iPad app in which I want to show animation when I start click on beginEditing here is the my code.

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSLog(@"This is calling");
    [self showAnimationPests];
}

-(void) showAnimationPests
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                     animations:^{
                         subView.frame = CGRectMake(0,-200,1024,748);

                     }];
}
```

It shows Log this is calling but view does not move.

Comment: What is `subView`? Could it be that `subView` is not referencing a valid view? Perhaps you can give us a bit more of your code?

Comment: What is subview here ?

Comment: subView is the view which i want to animate

Comment: `NSLog(@"%@", [subView class])` what does this give you if you put it in the animation block.

Answer (score 1):

If it's an iphone app why is the size of it `1024x748`?

`CGRectMake` takes points not pixels (if you are trying to make up for retina display). And those points for iPhone 5 are `320x568` and previous devices `320x480`.

Comment: But you state in your question:

`I am making the iphone app`

Comment: Anyhow, can you put some `NSLog` in your animation block, first output the `subView.frame` values then output them again after you have changed it to see if has changed.

Answer (score 0):

try with my bellow code

**Example..**

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    subView.frame = CGRectMake(0,-200,1024,748);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    return YES;
}
```

and set to 0 like default in `textFieldShouldReturn:` method like bellow..

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
        subView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,1024,748);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        return YES;
}
```

Comment: i do not want this way becuase i want to commit this animation on resignFirstResponder

Comment: @NativeDeveloper you can resign and set to 0 y like default with second method which i post :)

Comment: Delegate shouldn't be the problem as he says the `NSLog` outputs so the delegate method is being run.

Comment: @NativeDeveloper try with `self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,-200,1024,748);` instead of `subView.frame = CGRectMake(0,-200,1024,748);` and let me know..